# PayPal Developer: Under "MyAccount" I want to enable payout ... but 'they' need more info?

Tags: paypal, braintree, payout

Under Developer->MyAccound I want to enable payout (Payouts, Payout up to 500 recipients in one API Call).

**When pressing "Enable", info "To process your request we need more information about you and your account."** is displayed and link "Contact Us", taking me to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-phone.

Finally I created a post for the community https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Business/Developer-My-Account-gt-Payouts-gt-Activate-not-working/m-p/1431023, up to now w/o an answer.
We are currently evaluating a few payment providers for a marketplace-like service, where we need a checkout and a payout. The process is kind of special, as we usually do payouts only once per "person" (gift business, https://pres-it.com).

Answer (score 0):

PayPal REST API Payout is available in few countries only, the rest of the countries can use PayPal Masspay for sending payments to their customers. In order to find REST API Payout availability in your country please contact PayPal Customer Service team or you can get in touch with PayPal support team by creating a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com.